# How to keep form data through login process?

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-1.7

To optimize my page I want users to be able to fill out forms without being logged in, but then ask them for their password upon submission. I already know I can use &next= to redirect the user, but then all the POST data of the form is lost. Is there any built in way to have the user login and then resume to where he has been including post data he just sent?

Comment: what about session? what type of data is coming in? just text inputs or also files?

Comment: What about session? Can you elaborate a bit more clearly please?

Comment: In most cases just text. But I'm thinking of expanding this with files.

Comment: if you have file inputs, then session is not the choice. you need to save them into models and and depending on the last step, you delete them again or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you have also file in form, then session is not useful for you.

Second solution is save data into models and after login, you can use saved data to link with logged in user as said by @doniyor.

The best way is to use django-formwizard.

Django comes with an optional “form wizard” application that splits forms across multiple Web pages. It maintains state in one of the backends so that the full server-side processing can be delayed until the submission of the final form.

Here the link.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/